# Kinect2 C++ get Indices for Face Triangle vertices

Tags: c++, 3d, kinect

I want to debug the face mesh generated from kinect 2 sensor's HD face tracking.

I can get the Vertex data using `CalculateVerticesForAlignment` however I don't know the index for these vertices to form triangles.

I tried to use `result = GetFaceModelTriangles(TriangleCount, TraingleIndices)` but the resukt it returns is not S_OK and Traingle indices are not a multiple of three meaning `GetFaceModelTriangles` does not gives the indices.

The C++ KInect API documentation is very poor so I don't know if `GetFaceModelTriangles` even does what I think it does.

Comment: Have you tried the HD Face Basics c++ example provided by kinect?

Comment: @RafafTahsin It has no info on triangle vertex indices

Comment: http://vitruviuskinect.com/hd-face/ migh help

Comment: @RafafTahsin thats c# api some of whose fields are not present in C++ kinect api at all , Microsoft is trying push its C# down our throats so hard that it basically didn't even complete kinect C++ API

Comment: Oh ... bro ... my windows pc is not working for days ... otherwise i'd try it ... :(